# RSpec descriptions: Why does the `should` come before the method that should be causing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Below is passing code based on the example in the [RSpec book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book).

In the `describe "#start"` block, why does `should_receive...'Welcome to Codebreaker!` come before `game.start`?

It seems to me that the text wouldn't be put until the start method is called. However, if I reorder those two lines, the test no longer passes.

Why is this?

**lib/codebreaker.rb**

```
module Codebreaker
  class Game
    def initialize(output)
      @output = output
    end

    def start
      @output.puts "Welcome to Codebreaker!"
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/codebreaker_spec.rb**

```
require 'codebreaker'

module Codebreaker
  describe Game do
    let(:output) { double('output') }
    let(:game) { Game.new(output) }

    describe "#start" do
      it "sends a welcome message" do
        output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to Codebreaker!')
        game.start
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It *isn't* put before the `should_receive`, but if you instrument after it's called, it won't record the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official doc: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-5/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message

"Use should_receive() to set an expectation that a receiver should receive a message **before** the example is **completed**."

Read the two bold words above you may have a better understanding of this method. When you set `should_receive()`, it established an expectation and will watch the code run below in this example(it block)

So this method only makes sense if you set it before and run the code later. This should be able to explain your question.

Comment: Thanks Billy. I see that this is specific to `should_receive()`. My confusion was that I was mixing them with the other `should` methods which are sometimes called after an action is called.

Answer (score 1):

In this block

```
  it "sends a welcome message" do
    output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to Codebreaker!')
    game.start
  end
```

It is expecting output to receive puts with 'Welcome to Codebreaker!' ok? So, after the expectation was created the code runs and the test passes.

If you change the order of the lines you will run the code and after that you create a expectation that will not happen because the output will never receive "puts", and the test will fail.

With rspec you should always create an expectation and make it happen, in that order

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm confused because in the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/), he always uses `let` and `before` blocks first to set instance variable/login/visit pages, then tests what `should` be valid/viewable/logged_in. He also uses the `capybara` gem. Do you think that's the cause of the difference?